# Formula to determine available options based on prerequisites

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Example:
A spreadsheet for a single studient has four columns: Course|Completed?|Prerequisites|Available

The "Course" column lists the names of courses.
The "Completed?" column indicates a "yes" if the student has completed the course.
The "Prerequisites" column contains a comma delimited list of courses that the student needs to have completed in order to be able to take the course in that row's "Course" column; all courses that appear in this column are in some row in the "Course" column.

The goal is to put a formula in the "Available" column that will indicate "yes" if each of the courses in the "Prerequisites" column has a "yes" in the "Completed" column for that course's row. If there was only one prerequisite, this would be a simple vlookup. However, since there can be an indeterminate amount of courses listed here, I need to parse the courses out and perform a variable amount of vlookups based on the number of prerequisites.

Is there an easy way to do this without using any VBA code? Perhaps using an array with sumproduct?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. Even with VBA (although your mileage of "easy" may vary). It is never easy to use formulas or VBA to compensate for bad data architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is in e.g. A1:D10 (with headers in row 1, so that *Course*, *Completed?*, *Prerequisites*
and *Available* are in A1, B1, C1 and D1 respectively), and also assuming that the entries in the *Prerequisites* column are each separated by the precise combination of a single comma followed by a single space, then enter this formula in D2:

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(0+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&$A$2:$A$10&", ",", "&C2&", "))),0+($B$2:$B$10="Yes"))=1+LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","")),"Yes","No")

Copy down as required.

Regards